# Why do I get undefined plus the value?

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm very new to JS and I'm just playing around with syntax.

When I call

```
budgetController.publicTest2();
```

I get:

> 46 Undefined

I expected the 46 but why do I also get Undefined?

Full Code:

```js
var budgetController = (function() {
    var x = 23;

    function add(a) {
        return a + x;
    }

    return {
        publicTest: function() {
            const y = add(23);
            return y;
        },
        publicTest2: function() {
            return (function(d){
                console.log(d());
            })(budgetController.publicTest);
        },
    }
    })();
    
budgetController.publicTest2();
```

Comment: Are you running this in a console or some repl? It doesn't log `undefined`, but the result of `budgetController.publicTest2()` is undefined. You should consider making this a runnable snippet (with the `<>` button in the editor) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I made it a runnable snippet but I don't see it in the snippet console. I see it in firefox/chrome.

Comment: Nice, Vedran's answer below explains the behavior. The console is just printing the value returned by the function, which is undefined because it's not returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console prints out `undefined` because that is the return value of the `budgetController.publicTest2()` expression.

Console always prints out the value of the expression that you entered. For example:

- If you type in `1 + 2`, you will get `3` back.
- If you type in
  `console.log(3)` you will get back `3` and `undefined` (the return
  value of the expression `console.log(3)`)

Comment: Yeah I see that happening... I guess I just never noticed that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't I get multiple 'Undefined' since it's calling PublicTest and then the add() function?

Comment: When i call  `budgetController.PublicTest2()`  using the code below, I don't get undefined. I just get the number result:



`var budgetController = (function() {`
    `var x = 23;`

    `function add(a) {`
        `return a + x;`
   ` }`

    `return {`
        `publicTest: function(el) {`
            `return add(el);`
        `},`
        `publicTest2: function() {`
            `return (function(d){`
                `return d(100);`
            `})(budgetController.publicTest);`
        `},`
   `}`
`})();`

Comment: Exactly, you get the number result because it is the result of the expression `budgetController.PublicTest2()`. In the original example, you did not have return statement inside `PublicTest2` function, so the return value of that function was implicitly `undefined`.